# how to count appearance of a given key in nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data where the key `count` appears 6 times and it is nested. I'm trying count the number of times it appears with below logic but somewhat I'm close to it not got the exact result.

The problem is child values I'm getting as 7 which I have consoled. but the final count is always 1 seriously I don't know why I'm getting 1. Any help!

```js
let data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "child": [
           {
            "id": "1234"
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "child": [
        {

          "id": "42",
          "child": [
            {

              "id": "43"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

const countChild = (arr,cnt = 0) => {
  for (const {child} of arr) {
    cnt = cnt + 1
    console.log("child",cnt)
    if(child) countChild(child, cnt)
  }
  return cnt;
};
console.log("Final count",countChild(data))
```

Comment: In your code cnt is in local scope so and as you are using recursion its keeping the cnt values associated with its context, so when its emptying the call stack the cnt value is 1, you need to put the cnt in global scope o JS wont make the local copies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a `reduce` function for that:

```js
const countData = (arr: any) => {
    return arr.reduce((results: number, elm: any) => {
        if (!!elm.child) {
            results += (1 + countData(elm.child));
        }

        return results;
    }, 0);
};
```

But if you still want to use your function, it needs to be adapted as below:

```js
const countChild = (arr,cnt = 0) => {
  for (const {child} of arr) {
    if (child)
        cnt = 1 + countChild(child, cnt);
    console.log("child",cnt)
  }
  return cnt;
};
```

Comment: yes, but why my code is not working what's the problem. why it is returning 1?

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```js
let data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "child": [
           {
            "id": "1234"
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "child": [
        {

          "id": "42",
          "child": [
            {

              "id": "43"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

const flatChild = (arr) => 
  arr.flatMap(({id, child}) => [id, ...flatChild(child || [])] ) 

const countChild = arr => flatChild(arr).length



console.log("Final count", countChild(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "child": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "child": [
           {
            "id": "1234"
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "child": [
        {

          "id": "42",
          "child": [
            {

              "id": "43"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

let cnt = 0;

const countChild = (arr) => {
  for (const {child} of arr) {
    cnt = cnt + 1;
    console.log("child",cnt);
    if(child) countChild(child);
  }
  return cnt;
};
console.log("Final count",countChild(data));
```

here simply putting the cnt in global scope so the JS will not make local copies for each recursive function